# Access not going to new record

Tags: sql, ms-access, ssms, ssms-2016

I have an access app that is quite complicated and old, and really shouldn't be in access at all.

I am trying to add a new form.  I copied the old form and changed the SQL table names to the new ones. I added test data in SQL and everything looks fine.

However I can't add new records.  The other forms have a new button that works, or you can just click on the little arrow at the bottom.  In this case it's greyed out.

The New button gives me error 2046 The command or action RecordsGoToNew isn't available now.  Tried both and they don't work.

```
' DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
  DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
```

What am I missing?  I don't use Access often and this code is so old I'm having a hard time understanding it.  There is a lot of on error resume next. So I don't think it's written well either.  But that's not the point.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

ETA I think this might be an SSMS issue and tagged it as such.  If I do an unlinked table it works.  What would cause that to happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your form use a table or SQL for the record source? If SQL, does it include all fields in the table?  Are there multiple tables? Does your form property Allow Additions = Yes?  Where is that code located? Which event?

Comment: Does your form use a table or SQL for the record source? If SQL, does it include all fields in the table? **SQL, yes**.  Are there multiple tables? **Two, Header and Subform.  Both display in Access correctly if I add them in in SSMS.** Does your form property Allow Additions = Yes?  **yes** Where is that code located? Which event? **On Click**  **ETA -
 Thanks**

Comment: I meant are there multiple tables in the SQL used as the record source? Have you tried to use your SQL in the query window to add a new record, and are you able to do that? If not, the query is not updatable, thus neither will your form be.

Comment: I'm not understanding. There is a main form and subform in Access which correspond to the SQL tables. How do I test to see if the query is updatable? There is no query associated with that button.  Just the code above.   I copied and pasted the access and SQL tables/forms and just changed the names from Header_ABC to Header_XYZ   Is it a SSMS issue? I don't know.

Comment: (1) open the form in design view; (2) look at the 'record source'property for the form; (3) it should contain either: (a) tablename, (b) query name, or (c) SQL. (4) if it shows a query name, locate that query and run it. Are you able to add a record to your database? (5) if it shows SQL, then copy the entire content of the SQL, and:(a) open query designer; (b) go to SQL view; (c) paste the SQL from the property sheet; (d) run the query and see if you are able to add a record to your database.

Comment: RecordsGoToNew is not found anywhere. It's called a lot in the program but it is not a query and isn't anywhere in the VB code.

Comment: If I right click on the detail of the main form, the Record Source is SQL and works in SSMS.  However, it is just a select.  SELECT dbo_Headers_Plastics.* FROM dbo_Headers_Plastics;
Allow additions is set to yes. The table is linked in Access and I can click on it and see my test data.

Comment: Since the SQL doesn't do any filtering, sorting, calcs, could just reference the table in the RecordSource. If you can add data directly to the table and still can't in the form, then something wrong with form design.

Comment: I'm confused now... in your original post you said you have tried both "DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec  and  
  DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew".  If you have a button that you click, then that will execute either a macro or vba code.  Please explain, provide code! Maybe your 'add record' is in the main form but needs to be in the subform.

Comment: Sorry. There is a button called New with that exact VBA code.  No explanation. I tried both and neither works.  Plus I can't click on the little arrow at the bottom.  It works with the other two forms, so I'm not sure how just coping and pasting the two forms and changing the names killed it.

Comment: Private Sub cmdNew_Click()

' DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
 DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew                                                     
 End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Thank you for your help everyone.  I created an unlinked version of the tables to narrow it down.  That worked so I knew it was an issue with the database and not Access.  My tables were identical.

I readded the tables in and I think my problem was I didn't select the primary key or I selected the wrong one.  I could tell that helped. But it still didn't fix it.

I did notice that some columns that do have nulls before it's finished were set to not allow nulls.  So I changed that and got it to work.  I have no idea how the others are working but this program is so bad and breaks all the time so I'm just going to run with it and keep moving forward.  It isn't life or death information and I'll test it like crazy.

Thanks again everyone.